# Creating Pi small touchscreen menu in Election

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, electron

I've got a Pi4 4GB and a Waveshare 4.3" touchscreen and I'm wanting to build a cyberdeck. i3wm is OK, but I'd prefer to have a custom fullscreen touch menu. Pimenu uses Python2 and doesn't seem to have been updated in forever, so I wanna build my own version that uses Electron and JSON to load menu items. But here's what I'm trying to figure out: is there a way to run it behind the other windows or as the wallpaper? I know you could do this with Gnome/X11, but I have no idea with this Wayland/Wayfair/whatever.

What I mean is: I want the menu to open an app, and when I close the app, I want the menu to reappear. I'm not tiling windows on an 800x480 touchscreen, I'm trying to figure out how to open every app fullscreen or maximized by default, but I'll be happy if someone can point me to how to make a fullscreen touch menu in Electron that runs behind every other window (and maybe even the menubar) in Raspberry Pi OS.

Thanks!

Comment: what's `election`?